# How to even listen to Notification service when the app is destroyed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an Notification Listener app in which , i am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_notification_listener for listing of the notifications . The problem with this is when ever the app is destroyed or removed from recents it stops working and says " flutterjni was detached from native c++...... .

That means the flutter engine is not there to read the notifications data that is coming from the android(native) side . What can be possible work arounds this ?

---

**CODE to the Notification listner : **

```
`import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_notification_listener/flutter_notification_listener.dart';
import 'package:simple_pip_mode/simple_pip.dart';

class NotificationsLog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationsLogState createState() => _NotificationsLogState();
}

class _NotificationsLogState extends State<NotificationsLog> {
  List<NotificationEvent> _log = [];
  bool started = false;
  bool _loading = false;

  ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();

  @override
  void initState() {
    initPlatformState();
    super.initState();
  }

  // we must use static method, to handle in background
  @pragma(
      'vm:entry-point') // prevent dart from stripping out this function on release build in Flutter 3.x
  static void _callback(NotificationEvent evt) {
    print("send evt to ui: $evt");
    final SendPort? send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("_listener_");
    if (send == null) print("can't find the sender");
    send?.send(evt);
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    NotificationsListener.initialize(callbackHandle: _callback);

    // this can fix restart<debug> can't handle error
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping("_listener_");
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(port.sendPort, "_listener_");
    port.listen((message) => onData(message));

    // don't use the default receivePort
    // NotificationsListener.receivePort.listen((evt) => onData(evt));

    var isRunning = (await NotificationsListener.isRunning) ?? false;
    print("""Service is ${!isRunning ? "not " : ""}already running""");

    setState(() {
      started = isRunning;
    });
  }

  void onData(NotificationEvent event) {
    setState(() {
      _log.add(event);
    });

    print(event.toString());
  }

  void startListening() async {
    print("start listening");
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    var hasPermission = (await NotificationsListener.hasPermission) ?? false;
    if (!hasPermission) {
      print("no permission, so open settings");
      NotificationsListener.openPermissionSettings();
      return;
    }

    var isRunning = (await NotificationsListener.isRunning) ?? false;

    if (!isRunning) {
      await NotificationsListener.startService(
          foreground: false,
          title: "Listener Running",
          description: "Welcome to having me");
    }

    setState(() {
      started = true;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  void stopListening() async {
    print("stop listening");

    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });

    await NotificationsListener.stopService();

    setState(() {
      started = false;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              SimplePip().enterPipMode();
            },
            child: Text('Listener Example')),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("TODO:");
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _log.length,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) {
                final entry = _log[idx];
                return ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      entry.tap();
                    },
                    // trailing:
                    //     entry.hasLargeIcon ? Image.memory(entry.largeIcon, width: 80, height: 80) :
                    //       Text(entry.packageName.toString().split('.').last),
                    title: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(entry.title ?? "<<no title>>"),
                          Text(entry.text ?? "<<no text>>"),
                          Row(
                            children: (entry.actions ?? []).map((act) {
                              return TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    // semantic is 1 means reply quick
                                    if (act.semantic == 1) {
                                      Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
                                      (act.inputs ?? []).forEach((e) {
                                        print(
                                            "set inputs: ${e.label}<${e.resultKey}>");
                                        map[e.resultKey ?? 'null'] =
                                            "Auto reply from me";
                                      });
                                      act.postInputs(map);
                                    } else {
                                      // just tap
                                      act.tap();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text(act.title ?? ''));
                            }).toList()
                              ..add(TextButton(
                                  child: Text("Full"),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    try {
                                      var data = await entry.getFull();
                                      print("full notifaction: $data");
                                    } catch (e) {
                                      print(e);
                                    }
                                  })),
                          ),
                          Text(entry.createAt.toString().substring(0, 19)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ));
              })),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: started ? stopListening : startListening,
        tooltip: 'Start/Stop sensing',
        child: _loading
            ? Icon(Icons.close)
            : (started ? Icon(Icons.stop) : Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i have tried every thing : flutter background service / flutter foreground service and many more .